# How to write XSD: List of double array (JAXB)

Tags: xsd, jaxb

How to define in XSD a List of 2d array?  In java like this: List<double[][]> myField;

Answer (score 1):

I would do it like this:

```
<xs:element name="myField">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="array2d" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="row" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                            <xs:simpleType>
                                <xs:list itemType="xs:double"/>
                            </xs:simpleType>
                        </xs:element>
                    </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

So the actual XML would look like this:

```
<myField>
  <array2d>
    <row>1.0 2.0 3.0</row>
    <row>2.0 3.0 4.0</row>
    <row>3.0 4.0 5.0</row>
  </array2d>
</myField>
```